# Javascript - object field is undefined

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I will try to just post the important parts of my program. If more code is needed, let me know.

**main.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mathematician</title>
        <meta charset=UTF8 />
    </head>

    <body>
        <span id=player_information>
        </span>

        <hr />

        <span id=exercises>
        </span>
    </body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

**script.js (compressed version)**

```
class Exercises
{
    constructor(player, number_of_exercises)
    {
        this.player = player;
        this.exercises = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < number_of_exercises; i++)
        {
            var exercise = new Exercise();
            var exercise_display = document.createTextNode(exercise);
            var input_field = document.createElement("input");
            var list_element = [exercise, exercise_display, input_field];
            this.exercises.push(list_element);
        }
    }

    display()
    {
        var exercises_area = document.getElementById("exercises");
        for (var i = 0; i < this.exercises.length; i++)
        {
            exercises_area.append(this.exercises[i][1]);
            exercises_area.append(this.exercises[i][2]);
            exercises_area.append(document.createElement("br"));
        }
        var check_button = document.createElement("button");
        check_button.innerHTML = "Check";
        check_button.onclick = this.check_exercises; 
        exercises_area.append(check_button);
    }

    check_exercises()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.exercises.length; i++)
        {
            if (this.exercises[i][0].check_guess(this.exercises[i][2].value)) {
                alert("That was wright!");
            }
        }
    }
}

...

var player = new Player();
player.display();
var exercises = new Exercises(player, 10);
exercises.display();
```

This program generates exercises and displays them with a text and an input field where you can enter the solution. If I click on the check button, I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: this.exercises is undefined
```

What was my mystake? I tried to figure it out, but this error message doesnt makes sense to me.

Comment: either bind the `this` to your functions as `this.functionname = this.functionname.bind(this)` in the constructor or use arrow functions as `functionname=()=>{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor you want to bind `this` to your display and check_exercises functions.

Try:

```
constructor(player, number_of_exercises)
{
    ...code...

    this.check_exercises = this.check_exercises.bind(this)
    this.display = this.display.bind(this)
}
```

Also 'right' is spelled without a 'w' ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the `this` object to your functions in order to use the `this` as your class object.

Because the `this` object in your function is basically referring to the `this` object of whoever is calling it.

Let,s say if you have an `HTML` code as:

```
<button onclick=Display()>Display</button>
```

the `this` object, in this case, will refer to the `button` and as the `button` object do not have any property called as `exercise` it is throwing an error as `undefined`.

So, what you can do is either bind the `this` object at the constructor as :

```
constructor()
{
  this.display = this.display.bind(this);
}
```

or you can declare your function as arrow function:

```
display=()=>{
 //my function code goes here.
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, both methods dont work. If I add "this.display = this.display.bind(this);" in the constructor, I get the same error message. If I try the second variant, the browser says "bad method definition".